# I need show in textbox link from and to property in gojs

Tags: gojs

i use flowchart of gojs and i want when i click on link get from and to node and show in textbox?

i tried some way but i cant find anythings

anyone can help me i really need that

```
     myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(
[

  { key: "Alpha", color: "lightblue" },
  { key: "Delta", color: "pink" }

],
[
  { from: "Alpha", to: "Alpha" },
  { from: "Delta", to: "Alpha" }
]);
```

in `{ from: "Delta", to: "Alpha" }`
show `from: "Delta"` in 1 text box 
and `to: "Alpha"` in other text box

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to implement a [click](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/GraphObject.html#click) event handler in your **Link** template.  The event handler's second argument would be the clicked Link, from which `link.data.from` and `link.data.to` would return the keys of the two connected node data objects.